# Does PierfrancescoSoffritti -android-youtube-player supports ads?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

Instead of using official youtube api I want to use PierfrancescoSoffritti -android-youtube-player found on Github https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

But I am confused whether it will allow ads to run on android app or not. The documentation on Github does not specify it. Can anyone tell me whether will will support ads or not? I have tried the following code to run youtube video. The video plays correctly but it is not showing ads. But if play the same video on youtube website then ads come.

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = "S0Q4gqBUs7c";
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This player is using the official web player from YouTube. Therefore ads are shown. But from what I've seen they seem to be shown less frequently than on desktop/native android player.

Comment: Thanks for your true help. God bless you.

Comment: In android 11 it is giving error saying "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID : XYZZZZZZZZZZZ) on every video link. BTW working fine below android 11 thanks for this awesome library

Comment: But that will be a real problem.. Android 12 is going to be launched soon.

Comment: @xaif set autoplay to false. That will help to remove the error.